# Why is that my servlet is sending complete JSONObject, but my android app see empty response

Tags: java, android, json, hibernate

I have a problem with receiving an empty response in Android from a servlet in Java.

I've managed to connect from Android app to servlet; my servlet proceeds request, execute successfully a query to a database, puts results into a JSONObject ( which I'm enable to display in my servlet), sends it ... and it's gone. My goal is to save the data from the response and screen it into some TextView fields.

The client app show that response is empty with error: "org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of".

In answers to other questions I've seen that people are confusing JSONArray tith JSONObject, but it's not the case in my particular problem.

UserProfile.java : server side

```
    package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import resources.HibernateUtil;

@WebServlet("/UserProfile")
public class UserProfile extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public HttpSession session;



    public UserProfile() {
        super();

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        doGet(request, response);

            if((request.getParameter("userId") != null )){


                String userId = request.getParameter("userId");


            SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            Session session = factory.openSession();

            String QUERY_GET_USER_TYPE = "SELECT pass, name, email, phone, city, adres, balance  FROM USERS WHERE ID = "+userId+" ";
            Query queryUser = session.createQuery(QUERY_GET_USER_TYPE);
            System.out.println("Query LOAD works ");

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Object[]> resultqueryUser = queryUser.list();

            System.out.println(resultqueryUser.toString());

            JSONObject objResponce = new JSONObject();

            for (Object[] str : resultqueryUser) {

                 try {

                     String pass= String.valueOf(str[0]);
                    String name = String.valueOf(str[1]);
                    String email = String.valueOf(str[2]);
                    String phone = String.valueOf(str[3]);
                    String city = String.valueOf(str[4]);
                    String adres = String.valueOf(str[5]);
                    String balance = String.valueOf(str[6]);


                    objResponce.put("pass", pass);
                    objResponce.put("name", name);
                    objResponce.put("email", email);
                    objResponce.put("phone", phone);
                    objResponce.put("city", city);
                    objResponce.put("adres", adres);
                    objResponce.put("balance", balance);


                    System.out.println(objResponce);

                    System.out.println("pass: " + pass + " , name: " + name);
                    System.out.println("email: " + email + " , phone: " + phone);
                    System.out.println("city: "+ city + " , adres: " + adres);
                    System.out.println("balance" + balance);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Obj Response: " + objResponce.toString());
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    response.getWriter().write(objResponce.toString());
                    System.out.println("Sended data from Send JSON:  " + objResponce.toString());


        };
        };





    }


}
```

UserProfile.java client (Android) side:

```
package com.mypack.mycomp.kubas;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mypack.mycomp.kubas.HTTPCALL.HttpCall;
import com.mypack.mycomp.kubas.HTTPCALL.HttpRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    public HttpCall httpCallPost;
    public Global global;
    public String link;
    private static final String TAG = "UserProfile";
    int len = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_profile);

        if (httpCallPost == null) {
            httpCallPost = new HttpCall();
        }

        if (global == null) {
            global = (Global) getApplicationContext();
        }
        String userId= global.getUserId();
        String status= global.getUserType();

        String login = global.getLogin();
        TextView loginText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginText);
        loginText.setText("My login: " +login, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        TextView statusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        statusText.setText("My status: "+ status, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        httpCallPost.setMethodtype(HttpCall.POST);
        httpCallPost.setUrl("http://"+global.getIP()+"/kubas/UserProfile");
        HashMap<String, String> paramsPost = new HashMap<>();
        paramsPost.put("userId", userId);

        httpCallPost.setParams(paramsPost);



        new HttpRequest() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                super.onResponse(response);

                if (response.length() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "response is empty ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                };
                //Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "onResponse: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "onResponse: try ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse works");
                    Log.d("response", "Size: "+response.length());
                    String login = global.getLogin();
                    JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(response);

                    String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
                    String city = jsonobject.getString("city");
                    String adres = jsonobject.getString("adres");
                    String phone = jsonobject.getString("phone");
                    String email = jsonobject.getString("email");
                    String balance = jsonobject.getString("balance");

                        TextView loginText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginText);
                        loginText.setText(login, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                        TextView nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
                        nameText.setText(name, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                        TextView mailText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
                        mailText.setText(email, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                        TextView phoneText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneText);
                        phoneText.setText(phone, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                        TextView cityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityText);
                        cityText.setText(city, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                        TextView adresText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adresText);
                        adresText.setText(adres, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                        TextView balanceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balanceText);
                        balanceText.setText(balance, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }.execute(httpCallPost);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public void EditProfile(View view){

        Intent newActivity = new Intent(UserProfile.this, UserProfileEdit.class);
        newActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(newActivity);

    }

}
```

Data from Eclipse console

```
Hibernate: select users0_.id as id1_10_, users0_.adres as adres2_10_, users0_.balance as balance3_10_, users0_.city as city4_10_, users0_.confirmCode as confirmC5_10_, users0_.date as date6_10_, users0_.email as email7_10_, users0_.login as login8_10_, users0_.name as name9_10_, users0_.pass as pass10_10_, users0_.phone as phone11_10_, users0_.tolerancja as toleran12_10_, users0_.tolerancja_zakladki_min as toleran13_10_, users0_.tolerancja_zakladki_plus as toleran14_10_, users0_.type as type15_10_, users0_.zakladka as zakladk16_10_ from users users0_ where users0_.login=? and users0_.pass=?
Query LOAD works 
Hibernate: select users0_.pass as col_0_0_, users0_.name as col_1_0_, users0_.email as col_2_0_, users0_.phone as col_3_0_, users0_.city as col_4_0_, users0_.adres as col_5_0_, users0_.balance as col_6_0_ from users users0_ where ID=66
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@29a634a1]
{"balance":"36.42","pass":"x","phone":"yyy--44444","city":"tggg","name":"xxxx","adres":"ggg","email":"mymail@gmail.com"}
pass: x , name: xxxx
email: mymail@gmail.com , phone: yyy--44444
city: tggg , adres: ggg
balance36.42
Obj Response: {"balance":"36.42","pass":"x","phone":"yyy--44444","city":"tggg","name":"xxxx","adres":"ggg","email":"mymail@gmail.com"}
Sended data from Send JSON:  {"balance":"36.42","pass":"x","phone":"yyy--44444","city":"tggg","name":"xxxx","adres":"ggg","email":"mymail@gmail.com"}
```

As you can see, my servlet is sending complete JSONObject. My client app also catches JSONObject. There is comunnication in other activities so the problem is not in Hibernate configuration (i guees).

Log from Android Studio:

```
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas I/UserProfile: onResponse works
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas D/response: Size: 0
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at com.mypack.mycomp.kubas.UserProfile$1.onResponse(UserProfile.java:75)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at com.mypack.mycomp.kubas.HTTPCALL.HttpRequest.onPostExecute(HttpRequest.java:68)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at com.mypack.mycomp.kubas.HTTPCALL.HttpRequest.onPostExecute(HttpRequest.java:20)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
11-22 13:53:15.883 2628-2628/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
11-22 13:53:15.919 2628-2775/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f5d86b9c020: ver 2 0
11-22 13:53:15.977 2628-2775/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f5d86b9c020: ver 2 0
11-22 13:53:16.263 2628-2775/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f5d86b9c020: ver 2 0
11-22 13:53:16.896 2628-2775/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f5d86b9c020: ver 2 0
11-22 13:53:17.888 2628-2775/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f5d86b9c020: ver 2 0
11-22 13:53:17.942 2628-2775/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f5d86b9c020: ver 2 0
11-22 13:53:19.910 2628-2775/com.mypack.mycomp.kubas D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f5d86b9c020: ver 2 0
11-22 13:53:21.701 2497-2730/com.android.calendar D/InitAlarmsService: Clearing and rescheduling alarms.
11-22 13:53:21.713 1526-1831/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 2572:com.android.dialer/u0a4 (adj 15): empty #17
11-22 13:53:48.077 1526-2879/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@207ccb7bcom.android.music.MediaPlaybackService$3@37444d98
11-22 13:53:48.080 1526-2878/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 2477:com.android.music/u0a37 (adj 15): empty #17
```

HttpRequest.java:
    package com.mypack.mycomp.kubas.HTTPCALL;

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HttpRequest extends AsyncTask<HttpCall, String, String> {

    private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(HttpCall... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        HttpCall httpCall = params[0];
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            String dataParams = getDataString(httpCall.getParams(), httpCall.getMethodtype());
            URL url = new URL(httpCall.getMethodtype() == HttpCall.GET ? httpCall.getUrl() + dataParams : httpCall.getUrl());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod(httpCall.getMethodtype() == HttpCall.GET ? "GET":"POST");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            if(httpCall.getParams() != null && httpCall.getMethodtype() == HttpCall.POST){
                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, UTF_8));
                writer.append(dataParams);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
            }
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                String line ;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    response.append(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        onResponse(s);
    }

    public void onResponse(String response){

    }

    private String getDataString(HashMap<String,String> params, int methodType) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean isFirst = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (isFirst){
                isFirst = false;
                if(methodType == HttpCall.GET){
                    result.append("?");
                }
            }else{
                result.append("&");
            }
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), UTF_8));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), UTF_8));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you used simple json to make json object..?

Comment: can you post the exception pls

Comment: "have you used simple json to make json object" Yes I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try..

1. Create a method to populate data..like this:

   ```
    public List<UserInfo> getUserInfo(String userId) {
      List<UserInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
     SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
     Session session = factory.openSession();

    String QUERY_GET_USER_TYPE = "SELECT pass, name, email, phone, city, adres, balance  FROM USERS WHERE ID = " + userId + " ";
   Query queryUser = session.createQuery(QUERY_GET_USER_TYPE);
   System.out.println("Query LOAD works ");

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   List<Object[]> resultqueryUser = queryUser.list();

   System.out.println(resultqueryUser.toString());

   JSONObject objResponce = new JSONObject();

   for (Object[] str : resultqueryUser) {

       try {
           // Variable with a diameter from this order
           String pass = String.valueOf(str[0]);
           String name = String.valueOf(str[1]);
           String email = String.valueOf(str[2]);
           String phone = String.valueOf(str[3]);
           String city = String.valueOf(str[4]);
           String adres = String.valueOf(str[5]);
           String balance = String.valueOf(str[6]);                
           UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
           userInfo.setName(name);
           userInfo.setEmail(email);
          list.add(userInfo);


       } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

        }
          return list;
     }
   ```

   1. Change servlet doPost method

      String userId = request.getParameter("userId");

      try {
           List> list = new ArrayList>();
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
          AccountNuberListDao accountNuberListDao = new AccountNuberListDao();
          for (UserInfo user : getUserInfo(userId)) {
              Map map = new HashMap();
              map.put("name", user.getName());
              map.put("email", user.getEmail());
              list.add(map);
              json.put("userInfoNodes", list);

      ```
      }          
      System.out.println(" userInfoNodes = " + list);
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setContentType("application/json");
      response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
      response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
      ```

      } catch (Exception ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(UserProfile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
   2. Create a class UserInfo

      public class UserInfo {

      ```
       String name;
       String email;

      public String getName() {
        return name;
       }
      ```

      public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
          }

      public String getEmail() {
              return email;
         }

      public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

      }

Comment: I think it will work.. it is working for me .. try it feel any problem feel free to tell

Comment: Thanks for help :) Unfotunetally it doesn't do the trick.  "

Hibernate: select users0_.pass as col_0_0_, users0_.name as col_1_0_, users0_.email as col_2_0_, users0_.phone as col_3_0_, users0_.city as col_4_0_, users0_.adres as col_5_0_, users0_.balance as col_6_0_ from users users0_ where ID=66
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@5e7bc824]
 userInfoNodes = [{name=xxxx, email=mymail@gmail.com}]" and still on the client side "org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of"